# Start-Process -ArgumentList switches for silently installing Altova software using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to silently install Altova software using the `Start-Process` command in PowerShell.

My issue is, I wish to change some of the options during the installation instead of keeping the default options for when you normally do a silent install.

The below code worked for installing Java:

```
Start-Process `
-FilePath '....\jre-8u201-windows-x64.exe' `
-ArgumentList @(
"REBOOT=0"
"INSTALL_SILENT=1"
"AUTO_UPDATE=0"
"WEB_JAVA=1"
"WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=M"
"WEB_ANALYTICS=0"
"EULA=0"
"SPONSORS=0"
"REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1") `
-NoNewWindow `
-Wait
```

I was wondering if I could modify this code to install Altova products silently whilst still being able to modify the default options during the installation.

Comment: Depends entirely on the installer in question, consult the vendor documentation

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for the guidance. I was wondering what the variables are called. Are they configuration file switches?